# Accessing web resources on a remote server from a local computer

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu server on my pc, and I want connect via the web browser on a remote computer but I don't know how to do that.

For example, I installed MediaWiki and to login from the local computer I navigate to `http://192.168.x.x/wiki`, but when I try to connect from a remote computer, entering my external IP or URL doesn't display the wiki.

So what I must to do access the web resources on my local computer from a remote computer? I've already Googled this problem but I don't understand a lot. For ex. I tryed to install Apache but I don't understand how configure it.

Finally I want set the domain like http://www.trytomakedomain.com/wiki

Thanks in advance (ps I'm new to Ubuntu) :)

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to AskUbuntu. I've edited your question while keeping all the points you made so that others will understand it better. If I lost anything in the process, then I apologise and you should go ahead and add them back in. Editing of questions is a thing that happens here on AskUbuntu, and if you want to know more about what this site's about, then I suggest you read both the 'About' section http://askubuntu.com/about and the FAQ http://askubuntu.com/faq. Simply asking a question here helps both the site and others who visit it, and I hope you'll ask more in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! From the question I see you're having more of a networking question rather than a Ubuntu question. This is because the ability to reach a machine behind NAT (as can be seen in the example IP address you provide) really is an IPv4 thingy to configure in the device doing NAT/Firewalling/routing in your network. Unless your router is running Ubuntu, these questions are considered more ontopic on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) being an AskUbuntu "brother" for networking questions.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question with few words.

You need to setup a port redirect in your CPE equipment, to forward port 80 to the IP (Internal IP) that your Ubuntu server has, 192.168.x.x.

You also need to set a DynamicDNS service, so you can be able to point http://www.trytomakedomain.com/wiki to your public IP which will change over the time

Take a look at this, and google about IP address public and private and port forwarding.

Google for port-forwarding with the brand and model of your ADSL or Ca

Comment: Thanks for reply, i've alredy try to use no-ip for DNS and port 80 is open but if i try tu put link of noip on browser nothing happen(link of no ip is (link to) external ip address), and in the server is installed client then the ip is ever update. More ideas? :(    And about "setup a port redirect in your CPE equipment" what do you mean? I've try to search in google but nothing find about. Thanks in advance =)